# FHIR - how to associate Encounter with Claim

Tags: hl7-fhir

Using FHIR (DTSU 2.1/3, as of 2016-03-01).

We have a requirement to associate charges to an encounters. 
So I am trying to find a way to associate an Encounter resource with a Claim resource. 
Ideally (it seems), Claim would just have a Reference(Encounter), but it does not. 
Is there a way to capture this relationship that I'm not seeing?
If not, would adding an extension to Claim that contains a Reference(Encounter) be appropriate to create this relationship?

For reference, here are the Claim and Encounter resource specs:
http://hl7.org/fhir/claim.html
http://hl7.org/fhir/encounter.html

Thanks!

Comment: The refernece sounds like the best way to do it. Where did you find the DSTU3? I can only see the DSTU2 on hl7's website.

Comment: @Klaus Ekelt, re: DSTU 3, we are using the DSTU 3 packages from HAPI-FHIR project. https://jamesagnew.github.io/hapi-fhir/doc_dstu2.html   It appears though that the former DSTU 2.1 will be "changed" into DTSU 3  http://onfhir.hl7.org/2016/01/21/fhir-publishing-plans/

Answer (score 1):

Claim is still a "draft" resource.  I'd recommend raising a change proposal on the resource.  I agree that a link seems a reasonable thing to include in core.